# Image of a connected set $f(K)$ is connected for $f(x,y) = x^2+y$ and $K = \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 | x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R $ , $f(x,y) = x^2+y$, and suppose $K = \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 | x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \}$, then I know that $K$ is connected but I want to show that $f(K)$ is also connected manually without using the idea that I already know that a continuous function defined on metric spaces maps connected sets to connected sets.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. All I have thought of is that 
$x^2+y > x^2+y^2 $ when $y < 1$, but $y < \sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $x<1$. I have to show $f(K)$ cannot be the union of two disjoint open sets but I am not sure how.
Hints appreciated.

Comment: I should comment that since we secretly know $f(K)$ must be a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$, we secretly know that $f(K)$ must be an interval. This makes it easy to figure out what $f(K)$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We claim $f(K) = [-1,\frac{5}{4}]$. First note that if $(x,y) \in K$, then $x^2+y \le 1-y^2+y \le \frac{5}{4}$ with equality holding when $y = \frac{1}{2}$ and $x = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. And, $x^2+y \ge y \ge -1$ with equality holding when $y=-1$ and $x=0$. So, $f(K) \subseteq [-1,\frac{5}{4}]$.

Conversely, given any $t \in [-1,1]$, letting $x=0$ and $y=t$ yields $(x,y) \in K$ and $f(x,y) = t$. Finally, given any $t \in [1,\frac{5}{4}]$, letting $y > 0$ be s.t. $1-y^2+y = t$ and $x = \sqrt{1-y^2}$ (it's easy to see $y < 1$), we get that $(x,y) \in K$ and $f(x,y) = t$. So, $[-1,\frac{5}{4}] \subseteq f(K)$.

We thus showed $f(K) = [-1,\frac{5}{4}]$, and it is a well-known result that intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ are connected.

Comment: I'm not sure how you chose $x,y$ for the interval $t \in [1, 5/4]$ can you elaborate?

Comment: Or why $(x,y) \in K$ for that matter.

Comment: Solve the quadratic equation $1-y^2+y = t$ to get some $y \in (0,1)$. Then let $x = \sqrt{1-y^2}$. It's then clear that $(x,y) \in K$.